# How to use c++ dll in C# code that works under XP?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-xp, filenotfoundexception

I have ran again to a problem I can't get across.

I am trying to use C++ DLL in C#. I get everything build successfully under my Win7 environment. But when I move these binaries to XP environment then I get an error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestDLL.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.at Test.Program.Main()

I have installed all of the C++ Redistributable packages (2005, 2008, 2010) but these didn't fix the problem.

I Tried using .NET v3.5 instead of v4.0 but it didn't help me as well. I am using VS2010.

Simple code to build I used to regenerate the problem on XP built on Win7:

C++ DLL:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestDLL.h"

namespace Test
{
    namespace DLL
    {
        DLL::DLL(void)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
using namespace System;

namespace Test
{
    namespace DLL
    {
        public ref class DLL
        {
            public:
                DLL(void);
        };
    }
}
```

C# Console app:

```
using System;
using Test.DLL;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                DLL a = new DLL();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

All these are built with x86, not Any CPU or x64.

What dependency am I missing? This problem has occurred on every XP I have tested. This has worked fine on every Win7 I have tested.

Comment: The typical mistake here, after ensuring you've got the redist DLLs installed like you did, is to deploy the Debug build of the assembly.  That can only work on machines that have VS installed.  Deploy the Release build only.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it didn't work. But i was using Debug. Now I used Release.

Comment: Next stop is SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You should see it searching for the missing DLL.  Google "enable loader snaps" for a less noisy way.

Comment: It was my bad. I copied to my VirtualM XP Debug binaries not Release. I tryed it again today and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Hans, please make an answer so I could accept it. =)

Answer (score 1):

I tested this also on XP. Got the same error, used ProcMon and saw that MSVCR100.dll was missing. Installed Microsoft [Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5555) and everything works now. No more error. 
And also builded the application as Release..

Did you use ProcMon to see what's missing on your system?